# SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a problem with my SQL query that take time to get all records from database. Any body help me. Below is a sample of database:

```
order(order_id, order_nm)
customer(customer_id, customer_nm)
orderDetail(orderDetail_id, order_id, orderDate, customer_id, Comment)
```

I want to get latest customer and order detail information.
 
Here is may solution:

I've created a function that GetLatestOrderByCustomer(CusID) to get lastest Customer information.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLatestOrderByCustomer]
(
    @cus_id int
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar varchar(255)

    SELECT @ResultVar = tmp.comment
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 orderDate, comment
        FROM orderDetail
        WHERE orderDetail.customer_id = @cust_id
    ) tmp


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar

END
```

Below is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
      customer.customer_id
    , customer.customer_nm
    , dbo.GetLatestOrderByCustomer(customer.customer_id)
FROM Customer
    LEFT JOIN orderDetail
        ON orderDetail.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

It's take time to run the function. Could anybody suggest me any solutions to make it better?

Comment: you need to stop thinking procedurally. use a set based join rather than calling a function

Comment: you should select an answer as "correct" when it works for you.  you click on the large check mark next to the answer you like best.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
   SELECT c.customer_id
        , c.customer_nm
        , y.comment
     FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT od.customer_id,
                  MAX(od.orderdate) AS max_date
             FROM ORDERDETAIL od
         GROUP BY od.customer_id) x ON x.customer_id = c.customer_id
     JOIN (SELECT od.customer_id,
                  od.comment,
                  od.orderdate
             FROM ORDERDETAIL od) y ON y.customer_id = c.customer_id
                                   AND y.orderdate = x.max_date
```

There's no need for the function - use a derived table/inline view/subquery.  The reason your function performs poorly is because it is executing for every row returned.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've applied your suggestion in my SQL query. Then, Amazing! It's completely reduce the cost in my SQL query. It's take some seconds to get all my data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1, too bad you'll probably never get this answer "selected" as correct

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper indices?

- custoemr.customer_id,
- orderDetail.customer_id

should both be indexed. As should possibly be oder.OrderDate. Without indices you run table scans galore - and you dont say anything about WHY your query is slow, so assuming bad indexing is something i normally do.

I find it funny that the customer_id is on the order detail, not on the order - normally orders are asssigned to one customer.

Now, fundamentally wrong:

The function GetLatestOrderByCustomer does not do that ;) There is a TOP 1 but there is no - ORDER BY. SQL Results have no determined order unless you say so, so the one element returned is esentially - RANDOM.

If the customer_id is a growing number, there is no need to have a function. Get rid of it, and merge the query part into the main SQL Query - allows the query optimizer to do better work.

Then - the id fields should not be strings. Seriously - you blow performance there, big time. Make them small, efficient. int, smallint. Do not use them for the "end user" coding (invoice number etc.) - that can be a separate string field with unique index. But joining strings - especially defined as varchar(255) is quite slow compared to joins in ints.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry for my mistake customer must be on order table. I've just make a sample in my case to be simple. I agree with you that should both be indexed and better of integer data type and also joining strings by defining varchar(255). Thanks so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your database, using an `OUTER APPLY` might be much faster then the solution provided by @OMG Ponies:

```
SELECT c.customer_id
, c.customer_nm
, y.comment
FROM customer c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 o.comment
    FROM orderdetail o
    WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ORDER BY orderDate DESC
) AS y
```

See query execution plans below. Note the query cost relative to batch (top plan is `OUTER APPLY`, bottom plan is @OMG Ponies solution; other queries in batch are inserts into temporary tables):

[image: query execution plans]